# Meteor pattern practices - handling data at rendered

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a non-meteor javascript library that needs to know at its load time some of what is in `this.data`.

I've setup my routes to work with the very newest iron:router, and the rendered callback has data in `this.data` when I navigate to the page via links - but not directly (I'm pretty sure this has something to do with my understanding gap of how meteor renders pages)

But it appears that meteor is rendering without data, i.e. `this.data` is `null`... Anyway, here is my route configuration: (onBeforeAction('loading') doesn't seem to help although I've read a lot about it on stack overflow...)

```
Router.route('/item/view/:_id', {       
    name: 'viewItem',
    yieldRegions: {
        'viewItem': {to: 'mainContent'}
    },
    subscriptions: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('items',this.params._id);
    },
    data: function () {     
        return ItemsCollection.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    },
    action: function() {
        if(this.ready()){
            console.log('RENDERING');
            this.render();
        } else {
            console.log('NOT READY'); //never called
        }
    }
});
```

I've tried lots of different configs, but they don't work either... If anyone has any more knowledge in this space, I would love to know it!

- one of those things is changing 'subscriptions' to 'waitOn'

Comment: You need to [waitOn](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#the-waiton-option) the subscription in order for `ItemsCollection` to have the necessary data prior to rendering your template.

Comment: thanks for that, but unfortunately that is one of the things I've tried already :(